# reload page from bean with url parameters

Tags: jsf, url, parameter-passing

I want to reload a page, after clicking a button which imports a file and does some backend-stuff.

This works well, but when the page reloads, the url-parameter is missing.

part of the code:

```
<h:commandButton value="File Upload" action="#{Bean.importFile}" >
</h:commandButton>
```

and in the Bean:

```
public String importFile(){
  //backend-stuff
  refreshPage();
  return null;
}

protected void refreshPage() {
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  String refreshpage = fc.getViewRoot().getViewId();
  ViewHandler ViewH =fc.getApplication().getViewHandler();
  UIViewRoot UIV = ViewH.createView(fc,refreshpage);
  UIV.setViewId(refreshpage);
  fc.setViewRoot(UIV);
}
```

the url is: http://localhost:8080/ca/process.html?pid=12345

the Bean has a managedProperty to get the processId.

So, if I click the button the reloaded page is: http://localhost:8080/ca/process.html

How can I pass the ?pid=12345 to the URL in my Bean ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may want to redirect:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesUtil.getFacesContext();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
ec.redirect("redirection_url");
```

Comment: thank you :) it works fine with:

     `FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentIstance();
     ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
     ec.redirect("redirection_url");`

Comment: Unfortunately this is no way answers the question of how to keep the query parameters.